# Can one compare java.lang.Class objects with == in Java?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does Java guarantee that Object.getClass() == Object.getClass()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3738919/does-java-guarantee-that-object-getclass-object-getclass)

If I have a class such as

```
Class<? extends MyObject> aClass = ...;
```

can I then do:

```
if (aClass == MySubObject.class) { ... }
```

or do I have to do

```
if (aClass.equals(MySubObject.class)) { ... }
```

In addition, further to knowing the answer, I would love to know a reference i.e. where this is defined.

I prefer to use `==` if possible, because I find it more readable, and faster. (Obviously it's not *that much* more readable, or *that much* faster, but still, why use a more complex solution if a simpler solution is available.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3738919/does-java-guarantee-that-object-getclass-object-getclass

Comment: Another one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/928531/does-java-have-an-is-kind-of-class-test-method

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5997801/java-comparing-classes-with-or-equals-is-there-a-difference

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `==` but you gain nothing because that's exactly what `Class.equals()` does.

Class doesn't define an equals method, so it inherits from Object.  You can read the source to see this.

I use `equals` where possible as then I don't need to think about it.  When I am reading code (including my code) I still don't need to ask myself is `==` the same as `equals` or not for this class.

Comment: Yes, you gain something: `==` is null safe.

Comment: @yankee true, in which case you could write. `MySubObject.class.equals(aClass)`

Answer (score 5):

You can compare classes with `==`, and that's the same thing as `equals` for the case of `Class`, but your example suggests that you want to know whether one class has an "is-a" relationship with another. Two classes are only equal if they're the same class, and clearly `Vehicle.class != Car.class`.

If you want to know whether a `Car` is-a `Vehicle`, use **[`Class#isAssignableFrom`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom%28java.lang.Class%29)**.